# Unknown electrical wires in garage floor

Tags: electrical, wiring

I moved into a home about a year ago, and yesterday discovered some strange electrical wires coming out of the garage floor. It's near the door to the house in the garage. The wires have been cut and after using a multimeter, no current is detected. I've checked the electrical boxes in the garage, and I don't see these wires coming to them. The color combination is strange (2 blue and a red). Does anyone know what these wires might have been used for?
[image]

Comment: Possibly for a door opener control and never used. Typically an opener will have a button operator near the house door.

Comment: Something that would feed or detect signal to something that was positioned at that point in the floor.  A floor sensor to detect presence of a car?  A phone line for a camper van parked in the garage?

Comment: What is the wire gauge or size? It’s hard to guess with no scale they look smaller but larger than signal wires to me.

Comment: Where are you located?  So far as I know, wiring exiting via garage floor is banned in the USA.  But in any case, you'll want to try to find the far end of these - maybe near the breaker panel in your house if not in your garage.  See if you can find bluebluered wiring anywhere else (phones, doorbells...) in your house.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft thanks, will look around the house. Located in Illinois, which seems to have strict electrical codes.

Comment: It possibly could have been part of a three way switch setup. Is it condulet below the concrete? Just guessing as it is close to a door.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with conduit coming out of a slab. yes that could be part of a 3 way switch, blues as travelers and red the common. The wire would need to be 14 awg or larger in that case, the pipe could have been snapped off especially easy if it was threaded at the surface of the slab.

Comment: Yes, can you get us a closeup of where the wires exit the slab?